# Get user value before post

Tags: jquery

Users can make a painting on my site with jQuery drag and drop.

To save the content I use.

```
$('#mksave').click(function(){

    $("#topmenu").animateHighlight("#a7bf51", 4000);
    var div_contents = $("#print").html();
    $.post("save.php", { 'contents': div_contents });
    alert('Your painting is saved');
})
```

Here I take the content form div print and save it via the save.php file.

Everything is working so far.

What I want to do is when the use klicks mksave (so the function will run) the user gets asked to give a name for the painting and after that I'm going to send the variable with post.

So there must be some kind of alert screen which asks for a title.

The question is how can I get the alert screen with text field an save the given input in a var so the code will be like:

```
$('#mkopslaan').click(function(){

    $("#topmenu").animateHighlight("#a7bf51", 4000);
    var div_contents = $("#print").html();

    var name = //return value from user input
    $.post("save.php", { 'contents': div_contents,  'name': name });

    alert('Your moodboard has been saved.');        
})
```

So I don't want the name textbox always visible but only in a box which appears on the click.

Edit I wasn't clear.

**The user MUST enter a name.**

Comment: Simplest solution would be to use `prompt()` as mentioned in some of the answers. For a slightly more visually appealing solution you might want to consider one of the modal plugins for jQuery. I haven't used any of them myself, though, so can't give you guidance on which are good or how to code with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty ugly solution, but you can use `prompt()`:

```
var name = prompt('Give a name for your painting:');
```

When `[Cancel]` is clicked, the result is either an empty string or `null`. To force a user to give a name, you could create this wonderful loop:

```
var name;

do {
    name = prompt('Give a name for your painting:');
} while (!name);
```

Neater solutions are possible too, using things like [`jQuery UI Dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) but they require some implementation effort; it would definitely not be as simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `var name = prompt("Name your painting")`